# I need to change my Launcher Activity to Register activity

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.qz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="MyQuizz"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        <activity android:name=".ScoreActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".QuestionActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".OptionsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CategoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I would like to change is so my register activity is the launcher activity

Comment: can you show the whole xml for the one with the intent filter? or just post the manifest file

Comment: i dont understand, sorry im pretty new to coding@beastlyCoder

Comment: i'll edit it hold on

Comment: thanks @beastlyCoder

Comment: @beastlyCoder so i replaced your edit with my whole manifest file and my main activity is launching first when i run the app.

Comment: No, i know i was just editing your question to make it more clear to other people, I posted my answer on how to fix it

Comment: let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: @beastlyCoder nothing has workeed within the comments on this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace:

```
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with

```
<activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, unfortunately this didnt work its still launching the main activity first

Comment: does the app on your phone have the previous version installed? the one with main activity? If so, uninstall that version, and try it again

Comment: YES thank you, i replaced the code with the above code and uninstalled the app from the device and then ran it. It works fine now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is just a section of code from the question with a linebreak removed (or verbatim from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62645652/208273))

Comment: I actually saw the question and opened my android studio project and copied and pasted the code and i changed the launchr activity so..